# DB2 alternate or Eclipse Plugin during development

Tags: eclipse, git, db2, enterprise

At my firm we use Java along with DB2 to persist data. There are several tables and stored procs which have logic embedded in it. Since we follow Agile methodology, there happens to occur situations where multiple people are working on the same stored proc in Dev environment (we currently have just 1 Dev instance which 8 developers share) we end up with situations where people overwrite each other's changes. And since there is no version control directly associated with the DB2 client, the onus is on developers to copy paste their strored procs to Git which is seldom done.

What I want to know is, if there is an eclipse plugin or an open source free in memory DB against which we can test our stored procs and other DB related changes and once the developer is comfortable, only then move it to the real Dev instance.

Comment: It is wiser to ensure that each developer EITHER has  own private database (on personal device)  OR, each developer has their own private schemas in a physical database shared by developers. In that way, each developer has their own private copy of each database object, including routines.  This requires setup rigour and dedication, but with a devops approach and good SCM, it can be easy to instantiate a developer-copy of a specific version of the db-schema, and subsequently merge the work of different developers via your SCM tooling and overall schema-evolution control in a CI environment

Comment: @mao Dedication and Setup rigour are some attributes my dev team doesn't have. But yes, putting in a few constraints on actual schema can force people to do this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 Developer Edition is free an this includes Db2 BLU (columnar in memory)

Check it out [here](https://www.ibm.com/ms-en/marketplace/ibm-db2-direct-and-developer-editions/purchase#product-header-top)

Answer (score 0):

You could check h2 db in db2 mode. May be it won't work for complex stored proc. Another way to do it would be to move the stored proc in your vcs and deploy them by script to avoid developers overwriting each other work.